# Get exported function names from file in Typescript

Tags: typescript, function, generics, types, intellisense

I need to get exported function names from a file for intelliSense purpose.

let's say we have the following file with some functions:

```
//demo.ts
export const foo = () => {};
export const bor = () => {};
```

Now let import everything from the file and passes it to a generic function:

```
import * as demo from './demo'

function myGenericFunction<T>(module: T, functionName: ? ){
}

myGenericFunction(demo ,'foo');
```

The question is how to set the type of `functionName` to become like `foo|bar`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keyof T` just as you  would for the key of any other type:

```
import * as demo from './demo'

function myGenericFunction<T>(module: T, functionName: keyof T ){
}

myGenericFunction(demo ,'foo');
myGenericFunction(demo ,'bor');
myGenericFunction(demo ,'bar'); // error
```